# Override values for overlapping objects between two scala lists

Tags: scala

Let's say I have a bunch of Widget, where a Widget is

```
class Widget (sku: Int, label: String, name: String, description: String)
```

And I have 2 sources of Widgets:

```
List[Widget] wInventory = getWidgetsInInventory()
List[Widget] wCatalog = getWidgetsFromCatalog()
```

I want to use the name & label from the Catalog to override any matching widget in Inventory. The match criteria is when sku == sku.
If the `label` is missing in the catalog, override with constant value of `No Catalog Label` instead of leaving `label` as is.
The `wCatalog` list may be empty.  There may be no intersections at all, or both lists can contain the same set of sku's.

First draft of the code below. There must be a way to avoid running `find` twice, but because `find` returns `Optional[Widget]`, it started looking messy with lots `getOrElse`.  What's the cleanest way to do this?

```
case class MyWidget (sku: Int, label: String, name: String, description: String)

object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    def setOverrideValues(inv : List[MyWidget], cat: List[MyWidget]) : List[MyWidget] = {
      inv.map (k => {
        val realName = cat.find( _.sku == k.sku).map(_.name)
        val realLabel = cat.find( _.sku == k.sku).map(_.label)

        k.copy(name = realName.getOrElse("No Catalog Label"), label=realLabel.getOrElse(k.label))
      })
    }

    val invItem1 = new MyWidget(sku=1, label="invLabel1", name="invName1", description="invDesc1");
    val invItem2 = new MyWidget(sku=2, label="invLabel2", name="invName2", description="invDesc2");
    val catItem1 = new MyWidget(sku=1, label="catLabel1", name="catName1", description="catDesc1");

    val wInventory = List(invItem1 , invItem2);
    val wCatalog = List(catItem1)

    val updated = setOverrideValues(wInventory, wCatalog)

    println("done")
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `wCateogry`?

Comment: And, just to be sure, you don't want to override the description, right? Just the label and name?

Comment: wCategory should be wCatalog.  Yes, override only name & label, not description

Comment: Then this is not your actual code, `wCatalog.name` will not compile, seeing as `wCatalog` is a list.

Comment: Fixed code snippet to full working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to run `find` twice, just run it once and store the result in a value of type `Option[MyWidget]`.

You can then use `Option#fold` and pass in two functions: one to run when the option contains a matching widget, and another when no match was found.

```
def setOverrideValues(inv : List[MyWidget], cat: List[MyWidget]) : List[MyWidget] = {
  inv.map (k => {
    val wOpt = cat.find(_.sku == k.sku)

    wOpt.fold(ifEmpty = k.copy(name = "No Catalog Label")) {
      w => k.copy(name = w.name, label = w.label)
    }
  })
}
```

You could also use pattern matching

```
def setOverrideValues(inv : List[MyWidget], cat: List[MyWidget]) : List[MyWidget] = {
  for (k <- inv)
    yield cat.find(_.sku == k.sku) match {
      case Some(w) => k.copy(name = w.name, label = w.label)
      case _ => k.copy(name = "No Catalog Label")
    }
}
```

Both options would save you from repeated calls to `find` or `getOrElse`